# How do I check for duplicate entries, without querying the whole database?

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I have a page that checks to see if Meta Tags have been submitted for products and categories.

Its shows at the top, those that are missing.
But I need to also see if anything are duplicated - because you shouldn't really have two products with the same Titletag or Meta Description.

I already do it by extract ALL products Titletags and Meta Desc/Keywords, along with their titles.  But in theory, this is taking more work than in needs to over several hundred products, whereas I just want to find those where the Titletag, Meta Desc, or Meta Keywords are duplicated with at least one other.

How do I do that without running a Query to find all.  And then on each row, querying ALL again to check titletag, and then querying all to check for Meta Desc, and then querying all again to check for Keywords.

Is there a script where I can query a product, and ask if either of those three fields have duplicates anywhere else in the DB, without FOUR queries (three being embedded)?

Comment: If they do have duplicates, do you want them to be excluded?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this if you want to exclude any duplicate rows is just group by those three values and make sure `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1`. The downfall to this is that it typically won't work any other way, because if you group by three columns and they repeat, the remaining columns will be arbitrarily selected from another row.

However, if that's not a risk and you only want to select rows where those three values appear once, you can try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Comment: Don't you mean `COUNT(*) > 1`? He wants those rows with multiple entries.

Comment: @flaschenpost I misunderstood, I thought he wanted to *exclude* duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I would double the answer of @McAdam331 with slight corrections.

If you need the `(col1,col2,col3)` - tuples with more than one row:

```
 select col1, col2, col3, group_concat(id) as idlist, count(*) as anz
 from mytable 
 group by col1, col2, col3
 having anz > 1
```

in group_concat(id) you get all ids as a comma-separated list like (4,1,19).